# How to handle the exception "The method 'onLogin' was called on null"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Good day, I am receiving the following error when running code for my application:

*The method 'onLogin' was called on null*

*( 6100): Receiver: null*

*( 6100): Tried calling: onLogin("Succeed")*

I was trying to neaten my code by putting my analytics stuff within a different file, but doing so has brought up this error and it now no longer sends a "login" event to Firebase. I'm very curious to know why I can not use this method to achieve the same goal. Code:

**login-page.dart**

```
Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () async {
        FireBaseAnalyticsData user;
        String result = await signInWithGoogle();
        if (result == "Succeed") {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/specials-page'); //'specials' = tab-creation page
          user.onLogin(result); //track login
        }
        else
          print("error logging in");
      },
... //other code
```

**firebase-analytics.dart**

```
final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

class FireBaseAnalyticsData {
  void onLogin(var x) {
    if(x == "Succeed")
    {
      analytics.logLogin();
      print("Log in successful");
    }
    else
      print("Error delivering login stats");
  }
}
```

I am not getting any syntax errors with my implementation, but I seem to be missing something with regards to the logic of this. Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only declared `user` variable. you have to initialize it before using it in`user.onLogin(result)`

```
Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () async {
        final user = FireBaseAnalyticsData(); //TODO: Initialize user here
        String result = await signInWithGoogle();
        if (result == "Succeed") {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/specials-page'); //'specials' = tab-creation page
          user.onLogin(result); //track login
        }
        else
          print("error logging in");
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just created a user variable of type FireBaseAnalyticsData, but have not initialized it. You need to initialize the user variable for user.onLogin(result) to function properly. Just initialize it as shown below and everything should work fine.

```
FireBaseAnalyticsData user = FireBaseAnalyticsData();
```